# How to break up the value present inside the <option> tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I have doubt regarding  tag in html. In the HTML page, a drop down list need to display in the  part of some fixed width. Problem i am facing is, there is one option in drop down list has some lengthy statement which causing the entire dropdown list extended  part. So i want to break the particular option value to display in two lines. How to do that in HTML?. Thanks in advance.

Eg.:

```
 <select name="Greetings">
<option value="">Select Greeting</option>
<option value = "2010">Welcome</option>
<option value = "2020">Welcome to the land of peace and love</option>
 </select>
```

How to break the value of option2??

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/programming/customattributes/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't break the text up using the HTML `select` element.

But, there are 3rd party dropdown list controls available from vendors like [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) - [Telerik ASP.NET Ajax ComboBox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/programming/customattributes/defaultcs.aspx), you can try them out. If you google a bit, you'll also be able to get some free controls which can do the same for you.

Or you can rig your own control using `DIV`s and a little bit of JavaScript.

One more suggestion is using the same `select` element, and using the `title` attribute on the `option` elements like this -

```
<select name="Greetings">
    <option value="">Select Greeting</option>
    <option value = "2010">Welcome</option>
    <option value = "2020" title="Welcome to the land of peace and love">Welcome to the land of peace and love</option>
</select>
```

The `title` element will show a tooltip containing the whole text, when the user hovers his/her mouse over the dropdown option.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.

You can have a custom dropdown menu. This is a good one.

[jQTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)

Comment: Then what is the solution for this??

Comment: Is using a dropdownlist in your requirement?

Comment: **@Raja D:** Replacing the `<select>` with a custom JavaScript implementation (in an unobstructive way).

Comment: Can you use radio buttons instead of select element?

Comment: No i cant use radio button. It is a requirement.

Comment: Then you have to use a custom drop down like element.